# UnoGame, Can't figure out how to check for numbers on card and discard pile

Tags: java, oop

I'm making a Uno Game.
I have a question in a method im making called playCard(Card card).

My question is how do I check the number of my card if I'm only allowed to have one parameter in my playCard which is card, I've already made a different class called NumberCard that I was able to implement Numbers into the card and a color as well. *(NumberCard extends Card)*.

Is there something I need to type cast? and if there is what is it? I've been trying to figure out this one problem for more than 8 hours now.

Thanks!

Also I apologize if my question is ordered in a confusing way, it's my first time using StackOverFlow.

***Here is the exactly what I'm asked to make***

public void playCard(Card card):
 This method is called when a player wishes to play a specific
card from their hand. The method should validate that the card can be played, then update the
game status based on the game rules.

***Card Class***

```
package model.cards;

abstract public class Card {
    private Color color;

    public Card(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

***NumberCard Class***

```
package model.cards;

public class NumberCard extends ColorCard{
    private int number;

    public NumberCard(int number, Color color) {
        super(color);
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

***playCard method in Game Class***

```
    public void playCard(Card card) //confused on how to add numbers here!
    {
            if (card.getColor() == getLatestDiscard().getColor()) {
                // confused on how to add the numbers.
            }
    }
```

***Game Class***

```
public class Game {
    //Attributes
    private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;// shouldn't deck be 2d? how can I add the colors + the number at once?
    private ArrayList<Card> discardPile = new ArrayList<Card>();
    //ArrayList<>
    private int currentDrawn;
    private boolean playedCard;


    //Setters and Getters

    public ArrayList<Card> getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }
    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }
    public ArrayList<Card> getDiscardPile() {
        return discardPile;
    }
    public int getCurrentDrawn() {
        return currentDrawn;
    }

    public boolean isPlayedCard() {
        return playedCard;
    }
    public Player getNextPlayer(){
        Collections.rotate(players, -1);
        /*
        players.add(players.remove(0));
        ^^ adds to the end of the array list the first player while removing them from first part of list

        thought it would be better to rotate, thinking if I remove and add the player it might affect the cards in hand
        making them reset or something.
         */
        return players.get(0);
    }
    public Card getLatestDiscard(){
        return discardPile.get(discardPile.size()-1);
        // size - 1 == amount of cards that exist?
    }
    public Player checkGameOver(){
        for (int i = 0; i != players.size(); i++) //for loop doesnt loop?
        {
            if (players.get(i).getHand().size() == 0)
                return players.get(i);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void playCard(Card card) //confused on how to add numbers here!
    {
            if (card.getColor() == getLatestDiscard().getColor()) {
                // confused on how to add the numbers.
            }
    }

    public void playCard(Card card, Color color){
        card.setColor((color)); // Card sets color to the color picked?
    }


    public void draw() throws MaxCardsDrawnException {
        currentDrawn++ ;
        try {
            if(currentDrawn <= 2) {
                players.get(0).getHand().add(deck.get(0));
                deck.remove(0);
                if (deck.size() == 0)
                    rebuildDeck();
            }
            if (currentDrawn > 2)
                throw new MaxCardsDrawnException();
            } catch (MaxCardsDrawnException s) {
            System.out.println("You are only allowed to draw twice");
        }
    }
    private void rebuildDeck(){
        if (deck.size() == 0){
            deck.add(discardPile.get(discardPile.size() - 1));
            discardPile.remove(discardPile.size() - 1);
            Collections.shuffle(deck);
        }
    }
    public void endTurn() throws UnallowedCardException {

        if (isPlayedCard()) {
            if (Objects.equals(discardPile.get(discardPile.size() - 1), new SkipCard(Color.WILD)) ||
                    Objects.equals(discardPile.get(discardPile.size() - 1), new SkipCard(Color.BLUE)) ||
                    Objects.equals(discardPile.get(discardPile.size() - 1), new SkipCard(Color.RED)) ||
                    Objects.equals(discardPile.get(discardPile.size() - 1), new SkipCard(Color.GREEN)) ||
                    Objects.equals(discardPile.get(discardPile.size() - 1), new SkipCard(Color.YELLOW)))
            {
                getNextPlayer();
            }
        }
        else if (currentDrawn == 2) {
            getNextPlayer();
            currentDrawn = 0;
        }
        try{
            if (currentDrawn == 2) {
                getNextPlayer();
                currentDrawn = 0;
            }
            else
                throw new UnallowedCardException();

        }
        catch (UnallowedCardException e){
            System.out.println("You have to play a card or draw two cards!");
        }
    }



    public Game(ArrayList<Player> players)//9.2 description
    {
        this.deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        this.players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        this.players = players;
        this.currentDrawn = 0;
        buildDeck();
        distribute();
        discardPile.add(deck.remove(deck.size() - 1));

    }

    private void buildDeck() {
        this.deck = new ArrayList<Card>(100);
        for(int x = 0; x != 5; x++) //The function mentioned in my explanation down bellow.
        {
            if (x <= 3)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c != 23; c++)
                {
                    if (x == 0) {
                        if (c < 10)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c, Color.RED));
                        else if (c <= 18)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c - 9, Color.RED));
                        else if (c <= 20)
                            deck.add(new HitCard(Color.RED));
                        else
                            deck.add(new SkipCard(Color.RED));
                    }
                    else if (x == 1){
                        if (c < 10)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c, Color.GREEN));
                        else if (c <= 18)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c - 9, Color.GREEN));
                        else if (c <= 20)
                            deck.add(new HitCard(Color.GREEN));
                        else
                            deck.add(new SkipCard(Color.GREEN));
                    }
                    else if (x == 2){
                        if (c < 10)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c, Color.BLUE));
                        else if (c <= 18)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c - 9, Color.BLUE));
                        else if (c <= 20)
                            deck.add(new HitCard(Color.BLUE));
                        else
                            deck.add(new SkipCard(Color.BLUE));
                        }
                    else if (x == 3) // why does it say that x is always == to  3;
                    {
                        if (c < 10)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c, Color.YELLOW));
                        else if (c <= 18)
                            deck.add(new NumberCard(c - 9, Color.YELLOW));
                        else if (c <= 20)
                            deck.add(new HitCard(Color.YELLOW));
                        else
                            deck.add(new SkipCard(Color.YELLOW));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int c = 0; c != 4; c++)
                {
                    deck.add(new ChangeCard());
                    deck.add(new HitAndChangeCard());
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    private void distribute(){
    for (int x = 0; x != players.size(); x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7;i++ ) {
            players.get(x).getHand().add(deck.get(0));
            deck.remove(0);
        }
    }

    }


}
```

***Player Class (incase needed)***

```
package engine;
import model.cards.Card;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Player {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Card> hand;


    public Player(String name){
            //ArrayList<String> players= new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singleton(name));
            // I actually don't know what I did here ^
            //^ object ? is this what it means by "Constructor that initializes a Player object with the given name."
            this.name = name;
            hand =  new ArrayList<>();
       // players.stream().limit(4);//not needed or?
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say you need to learn about polymorphism and then apply it. Using it you probably could change `card.getColor() == getLatestDiscard().getColor()` to something like `card.equals(getLatestDiscard())` where the respective `equals()` methods do type checks, casting and more specific checks as needed. However, you might also want to think whether it really makes sense to have separate classes for colored and numbered cards. Why not have a single `Card` class that has color and number as its properties (I assume there will be an "action" property too - where number could be `null`).

Comment: @Thomas
Thank you for the suggestion, I'll actually start reviewing polymorphism right now.
I have no clue why my professor wants me to make two separate classes, one being Card and one being NumberCard, I'm honestly just following instructions to be able to get the full mark on this course. if it were up to me I would've made it into one class which would've made applying it easier.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).